# Servidor multihilo ¿cómo llamar métodos desde run() en java?

Tags: java

Buenas, el caso es que estoy desarrollando un servidor multihilo para un trabajo de la universidad, y estoy trabado en esto, que no sé cómo hacerlo desde hace ya 3 días, he probado a poner el método como estático, pero entonces me da muchísimos más problemas el código, importante remarcar que no quiero que me lo hagan, no escribo esto para que me hagan el trabajo, sólo quiero saber por qué tengo tantos problemas, y cómo lo harían ustedes:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

class SesionTCP extends Thread{
    Socket s;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    String entrada;

    SesionTCP(Socket s){
        this.s=s;
        try{
            in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            out=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        }catch(IOException e){
            return;
        }
        this.start();
    }
    public int helloserver(){
        String ip;
        try{
            entrada=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(entrada);
            //Obtenemos la IP del cliente que invoca al servidor
            ip = s.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return 0;
        }
        if (entrada.equals("HELLO "+ip)){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public void run(){

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int IDsesion = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000000); //Genero el ID sesion aleatorio

        if(SesionTCP.helloserver()!=0){
            System.out.println("ERROR: NO SE HA COMPLETADO HELLO");
            return;
        }

        try{
            out.close();
            in.close();
            s.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            return;
        }
        out.println("Su sesion ha quedado finalizada");
    }
}
```

Quiero llamar al método `helloserver` desde `run()`, para ejecutar una serie de cosas, y tener el código más limpio, al dividir en métodos todo lo que tiene que hacer, pero me da el error de que no puedo llamar a un método no estático desde un contexto estático. Sin embargo he probado a poner el método `helloserver` como estático y me da entonces errores de que no puedo llamar a un objeto no estático (entrada) desde un contexto estático...

Un saludo, toda ayuda será bien recibida, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para llamar a un método de un objeto desde un hilo no es necesario que extiendas `Thread`. Es más sencillo crearte un hilo que contenga en su `run()` lo que necesitas hacer y lo arranques:

```
Thread nuevoHilo = new Thread(){

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Instancio la sesion
        SesionTCP sesion = new SesionTCP(new Socket());

        //Llamo a su metodo
        if(sesion.helloserver()!=0){
            System.out.println("ERROR: NO SE HA COMPLETADO HELLO");
            return;
        }

        //Resto de código

    }
};

//Arranco el hilo
nuevoHilo.start();
```

#### AMPLIO

La opción de pasar todo a un contexto estático no servirá. Si quieres abrir varias sesiones con atributos distintos no puedes definir variables que deben pertenecer a un objeto en un contexto estático. Te compilará, te funcionará en una prueba simple, pero vas a encontrarte mil y un problemas en ejecución.

Comment: Osea, que lo que propones es que en lugar de tener ese constructor, y la clase que extienda thread, me creo una clase simplemente `class SesionTCP` y creo el hilo, hago el run, ¿y ahí ya hago todo? Me refiero con todo, a llamar a métodos, que serán los que dicten el comportamiento del `run()`

Comment: Aún así, haciendolo de esta manera, me da problemas con que no puedo llamar a métodos no estáticos desde contexto estático, ¿Debería simplemente tratarlo todo en el `run()`?

Comment: Imagina el método `run()` como si fuera el `main` de otro hilo. Es una comparación un poco tosca pero, si no tienes experiencia, es como mejor se me ocurre explicártelo. No sé dónde estás usando ahora el contexto estático que me cuentas. Deberías de implementar todo lo que puedas como te indico y si tienes algún problema específico puedes hacer otra pregunta señalando el código donde tienes problema. Con el código delante y el problema bien explicado es como se te podrá ayudar. Si nos comunicamos con comentarios no nos vamos a enterar.

Comment: De momento creo ir bien encaminado, el único problema era que quiero llamar métodos desde `run()` y no me deja, porque me dice que tienen que ser estáticos los métodos que llamo. En caso de poner los métodos estáticos, me, ¿dará problemas el server también?

Comment: @juancarlos fíjate que yo he llamado a un método que no es estático como `helloserver()` y no hay ningún problema. Creo que lo que me estás diciendo es que no tenga acceso a alguna variable que no es accesible desde su entorno. Te recomiendo que estudies bien las relaciones que deben tener las clases de tu proyecto y cuál es el mejor modo de tener acceso a esos métodos y variables. Pensarás que eso es lo que estás preguntando, pero mientras más código puedas avanzar por tu cuenta y si surgen problemas los localices lo más precisamente posible para que podamos ayudarte, en poco tiempo acabarás.

Comment: A ver, en lo que reside tanto mi lío y mi cacao mental, es en que tengo dos clases, una, la `class servidor`, que se encarga de abrir `serverSocket`, instanciar la `SesionTCP`, y luego ejecutarla mediante `.start()`. Por lo que debo, según he entendido, escribir su comportamiento en `run()` de la `class SesionTCP`, e ir llamando a diferentes métodos para hacer todo lo que se supone que debe de hacer el programa.

Comment: Voy a empezar de nuevo, y abriré una nueva pregunta para tratar esto, ya que por aquí es algo rollo. Muchas gracias!